# Is there a way to sum the values directly in C# without hitting cosmosDB and run a query?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to find a way to sum the prices held in an array, the way I am doing it now is to save the document to CosmosDB then run an additional sum(foo) query on it but I am thinking there must be a way so simply do that directly before I save the document to CosmosDB to save the extra round trip to the DocumentDB.

Example Document below.

The values I want to summarise are under:

`ApiInputObject.TransactionDetails.Items.Price` and there can of course be many items in the array.

I can only figure out how to get a single value out but that seems very inefficient.

```
{
    "InternalTransactionlId": "XXX",
    "DocumentType": "order",
    "ExternalTransactionId": "externalIdTest2",
    "OrderBotResponse": {
        "id": "XXX",
        "status": "pending",
        "checkoutUrl": "https://www.example.com",
        "items": [
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "color": "Midnight blue",
                    "size": "L"
                },
                "price": "500",
                "quantity": "1",
                "shipping": "0.0",
                "title": "ACME Title",
                "url": "https://example.com",
                "product_id": "XXX",
                "imageUrl": "https://example.com/image.jpg",
                "status": "pending",
                "shippingMethod": "default",
                "totalPrice": 500
            }
        ],
        "reference": "XXX",
        "currency": "SEK",
        "country": "SE",
        "language": "sv-se",
        "provider": "acme",
        "callback": {
            "refund": "http://example.com",
            "success": "http://example.com"
        },
        "shippingAddress": {},
        "logs": [
            {
                "t": "2019-08-24T20:58:04.844+08:00",
                "m": "Created"
            }
        ],
        "meta": {
            "error": 0
        }
    },
    "ApiInputObject": {
        "ApiKey": "XXX",
        "OrderType": "directTransaction",
        "SourceSystem": {
            "SourceSystemName": "ACME"
        },
        "SourceSystemCountry": "SE",
        "DestinationSystem": {
            "DestinationSystemName": "acme.com"
        },
        "DestinationSystemCountry": {
            "DestinationSystemCountryName": "SE"
        },
        "Brand": {
            "BrandName": "ACME"
        },
        "RequestedFeatures": [
            "NONE"
        ],
        "ExternalTransactionId": "externalIdTest2",
        "TransactionDetails": {
            "callback": {
                "refund": "http://example.com",
                "success": "http://example.com"
            },
            "items": [
                {
                    "attributes": {
                        "color": "Midnight blue",
                        "size": "L"
                    },
                    "price": "500",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "shipping": "0.0",
                    "title": "ACME",
                    "url": "https://example.com"
                }
            ],
            "test": "true",
            "reference": "XXX"
        }
    },
    "id": "XXX",
    "_rid": "XXX",
    "_self": "XXX",
    "_etag": "XXX",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 111
}
```

Comment: I would love to but the only thing I have is the CosmosDB part which is what I dont want to do? I dont know where to start really with my question, I tried searching for SUM JObject arrays etc but nothing popped out that seemed useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `SelectToken` to get your `JSON` data value. then use linq `SUM`

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(data);
var value = obj.SelectToken("ApiInputObject.TransactionDetails.items").Sum(x=>((int)x["price"]));
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NTSSIv)